# What would be an easy way to check if a `q-input` element is in a error state?

Tags: cypress, quasar-framework

I have q `q-input` with a `data-cy="inputEmail"` property

Is there an easy way to check if the `q-input` is in an error state ?

The `data-cy` prop is attached to the native `input` element and it looks like the only way is to use some relatively complex css selectors, for instance by checking if the input's parent's parent has a `text-negative` class ?

Comment: How does the `q-input` in error state looks like. Is any attribute added or something else? Would be good if you could provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally from an e2e perspective you want to test for what a user sees, for the presence/absence of the error message

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="inputEmail"]')
  .parent('.q-input')
  .should('contain', 'must be a valid email')
```

If you look at the DOM, nothing changes on the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that in the error state `text-negative` class is added to the element, so you can assert the presence of this class like:

```js
cy.get('q-input selector').should('have.class', 'text-negative')
```